# Changing source files encoding in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode4

We are developing primarily in C++ under Windows and write comments in Russian. So our OEM encoding is Cyrillic (Windows).

XCode 4 does not ask to specify file encoding when you add existing file to the project. And you can specify your encoding in the right pannel on per file basis.

How am I supposed to change encoding for more than 200 files?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select the files (one or more) in the Project Navigator. In the Utility pane, under the Text Settings group you can change the Text Encoding.

Answer (score 5):

Click the file in the Project Navigator, then open the Utility pane. Choose the File Inspector tab and look under the Text Settings group to find the Text Encoding popup.

Comment: This is how you change encoding of a one file. And I need tho change for all files of the project. There are more than 200 files.

Comment: I have encountered almost the same problem, the tricks works but after you close the xcode project and reopen it, everything is back to the original state --- the whole bits of files are unreadable.... Chinese is my case...