Xcode 16.0 doesn't display German Umlaute in source files
I am processing Latex source.tex files with a Swift app.
The source files contain German Umlaute.
After adding the source files to a project and opening the files,
the Umlaute are not displayed correctly.
I am pretty sure it is an encoding problem.
I wrote the following text to a Tex file, using TexShop V5.46:
Öse
Übel
Ärger
Dösen
Müde
Mängel
Schließlich

I saved the same content in three different files, which were encoded in UTF-8, ISO Latin 1 and Iso Latin 2.
I copied the files to a Swift project and opened the files.
All of them displayed the same content:
÷se
‹bel
ƒrger
Dˆsen
M¸de
M‰ngel
Schlieﬂlich

In the file Inspector I tried to change the Text encoding. However, there was no change at all.
By the way. Reading the file content to a String variable with the command:
let aString = try String(contentsOf: latexFileURL, encoding: .isoLatin2)

results in a valid input. Displaying the String with a SwiftUI TextView the Umlaute are displayed as expected.
Has anybody a solution, that the Umlaute are displayed properly in the Xcode text editor?

You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): 'Ärger'.encode( 'cp1252').decode( 'mac_roman') returns ƒrger. Valid for any encoding in ['cp1250', 'cp1252', 'cp1254', 'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_9', 'latin_1'].

@JosefZ, I already know the problem and the reasons. However, I asked for a solution in Xcode.

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459700/changing-source-files-encoding-in-xcode-4 ?

I have got the solution:

Open TexShop
Select Preferences
Set coding to Unicode (UTF-8)
Close TexShop
Open your project in Xcode
Select the source.tex file with the right mouse button
Select Open with External Editor
TexShop opens and a warning pops up, that the file is opened with a wrong encoding
Press OK
Save the file (command S)
Close the file
Umlaute in Xcode are displayed correctly.

